# Google Play Developer Console gives me the same opt-in urls for two different tracks

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

I'm trying to release two different versions of  my app on 2 different tracks:

```
- Open Beta Track

- Closed Alpha Track
```

However  both tracks give me the same opt-in url `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.myapp` so both groups end up downloading the same version of the app.

How can I "force" the beta testers to only get those on the `beta` track and the other testers on the `alpha` track.  I have used internal-app sharing and it works, the thing is that this is not automatic as with the tracks.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is the same because opting in only means that they're eligible for receiving one non-production APK.

To determine which one they will receive, Play sends the user the APK with the highest versionCode they're eligible for (based on which test groups they belong to), which should in general be the furthest away from the prod track that they're eligible for.

Hope that helps,